# Displaying JSON array in flask template

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

As someone new to jquery/AJAX and flask I've been having a hard time working this one out.

My app.py will run a search based on user input against a PostgreSQL database and then return the results to a table in my template.

The reason I require AJAX for this is due to sheer number of form fields, I don't want to have to re-enter information in them if I forget to select or add some more options to narrow my search down to a few results.

What I then attempted to do was get all this information returned as JSON, which I was able to do, just not in the right place - it spewed it out on a page of its own and I had a struggle trying to make this available to my jinja2 template.

I've now managed to feed this information back into the jinja2 template thanks to `event.preventDefault()`and can now see this information in the console when I load the search page.

My problem now is that I can return information from the generated JSON array to the template, its just wrong. I can make it select the first item in the array but it will not process my search queries (it did when it spat them out into the browser) and it doesn't really append to the table neatly, continuous searches just bung more `<td>` tags in and doesn't adhere to my table layout.

What I need it to do is run the query and provide the JSON with the search results, and then return this to my html template properly.

I've been trying at this one for a while so would appreciate any sort of help.

My app.py

```
from flask import request, jsonify
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask import render_template
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='postgresql://postgres:test@localhost/postgres'
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:test@localhost/postgres')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

app.debug = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
Bootstrap(app)
ma=Marshmallow(app)
# classes

class Sdctest(db.Model):
    startchass= db.Column (db.Text, primary_key=True)
    cusname= db.Column (db.Text)
    chassistype1= db.Column (db.Text)
    axleqty= db.Column (db.Integer)
    tyres= db.Column (db.Text)
    extlength= db.Column (db.Text)
    neck= db.Column (db.Text)
    stepheight= db.Column (db.Text)
    reardeckheight= db.Column (db.Text)
    siderave= db.Column (db.Text)
    steer= db.Column (db.Text)
    sockets= db.Column (db.Text)
    containerstwistlock= db.Column (db.Text)
    headboard= db.Column (db.Text)





class TableSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('startchass', 'cusname', 'chassistype1', 'axleqty', 'tyres', 'extlength', 'neck', 'stepheight', 'reardeckheight', 'siderave', 'steer', 'sockets', 'containerstwistlock', 'headboard')
tables = TableSchema()
tabless = TableSchema(many=True)

#routes
@app.route('/')

def index():

        return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/platform', methods=['GET'])
def platform():
        return render_template('platform.html')

@app.route ('/search', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def search():
    options = db.session.query(Sdctest.chassistype1).distinct().all()
    axleopts = db.session.query(Sdctest.axleqty).distinct().all()
    # enables passing user input to the variable
    # query parameters and their corresponding database columns
    param_columns = {
        "startchass": "startchass",
        "cusname": "cusname",
        "chassistype1": "chassistype1",
        "axleqty": "axleqty",
        "tyres": "tyres",
        "siderave": "siderave",
        "steer": "steer",
        "sockets": "sockets",
        "containerstwistlock": "containerstwistlock",
        "headboard": "headboard",

    }
    param_column2 = {
        "startchass": "startchass",
        "extlength": "extlength",
        "neck": "neck",
        "stepheight": "stepheight",
        "reardeckheight": "reardeckheight",

    }
    # Get all of the column filters where the parameters aren't empty

    filters = {
        column: request.form[param]
        for param, column in param_columns.items()
        if request.form.get(param, "") != ""
    }
    filters2 = {
        column: request.form[param]
        for param, column in param_column2.items()
        if request.form.get(param, "") != ""
    }
    # filter most columns using fuzzy match
    query = Sdctest.query
    for column, value in filters.items():
        query = query.filter(getattr(Sdctest, column).ilike(f'%{value}%')).order_by(Sdctest.startchass.desc())
    for column, value in filters2.items():
        query = query.filter(getattr(Sdctest, column).ilike(f'{value}')).order_by(Sdctest.startchass.desc())
    results2 = query.all()
    result2 = tabless.dump(results2)

    return jsonify(result2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

my ajax.js file

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        event.preventDefault()
        $.ajax({
            url: '/search',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
            $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                $('#myTable').append(
                    $('<td>').text(item[0].startchass),
                    $('<td>').text(item[0].cusname),
                    $('<td>').text(item[0].chassistype1),
                    $('<td>').text(item[0].axleqty),
                    $('<td>').text(item[0].tyres),
                    $('<td>').text(item[0].extlength),
                    $('<td>').text(item[0].neck),
                    $('<td>').text(item[0].stepheight),
                    $('<td>').text(item[0].reardeckheight),
                    $('<td>').text(item[0].siderave),
                    $('<td>').text(item[0].steer),
                    $('<td>').text(item[0].sockets),
                    $('<td>').text(item[0].containertwistlock),
                    $('<td>').text(item[0].headboard),
                )
                    console.log(response[i]); // idk if this works...
            });
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and finally my template html(pasted this elsewhere as its a bit large)

https://paste.pound-python.org/show/d6Zm37ivTOnphW7lHcaj/

Comment: I think you need to construct the right html structure for this to work for you. That is a `table` element should be followed with a `tr`  and then a nested `td`s. This will be the order in which you would need them. In the above table you just have `table` nesting `td`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite confused on your approach in this.

However, I see that you are using jinja templating as well as AJAX to populate your table. You only need one or at least both of them don't work for two reasons.

1. I don't see any code that adds the results on the jinja template like so

   `return render_template('platform.html', result2=result2)`

for this code block in your pasted html,

```
{% for item in result2 %}
<tr>
<td>{{ item.startchass }}</td><td>{{ item.cusname }}</td><td>{{ item.chassistype1 }}<td>{{ item.axleqty }}</td><td>{{ item.tyres }}</td><td>{{ item.extlength }}</td><td>{{ item.neck }}</td><td>{{ item.stepheight }}</td><td>{{ item.reardeckheight }}</td><td>{{ item.siderave }}</td><td>{{ item.steer }}</td><td>{{ item.sockets }}</td><td>{{ item.containerstwistlock }}</td><td>{{ item.headboard }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

2. You are just appending tds on MyTable on your AJAX code. 82Tuskers is right. Structure your html right.

If you want jinja approach, on submit, you can request a POST request to /search
and return a rendered template with the results as shown in reason 1.

If you want an AJAX approach, make /search purely POST and receive the json file from the backend and do append them with the proper html structure. You won't need the code block in reason 1 anymore since it should be an empty table in the first place.

Hope this can give insights.

Comment: Thank you, I've solved the problem today (thankfully) and it is essentially what you've said - I've made search purely POST and appended it into a correct table structure as suggested by @82Tuskers, I appreciate the help.